# PIXI JS Movie Clips and Loading Assets

Tags: movieclip, pixi.js

In order to do a Movie Clip in PIXI.js are you required to have a JSON file?  Is it possible to have the JSON inside the same file, especially if the movie clip is only a few frames and load the image like you load all other Sprites.

The only examples they have of movie clips is a bloated Fighter Jet example.  Is this method possible? As MovieClip extends Sprite.  I hoped to achieve this because I have multiple images with the exact same frame information and I did not wish to duplicate it all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    PIXI.loader
        .add('point', rootUrl + "images/games/faction/base_point_sprite.png")
        .load(start);
});

functions start() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> are you required to have a JSON file?

No. A MovieClip only requires an Array of textures. Those textures could come from JSON file, or from separate images.

> Is it possible to have the JSON inside the same file?

Not sure what you mean, but typically when loading in a Sprite sheet, you would have a png image plus a JSON file that corresponds with it.

Here is a MovieClip example that uses 4 separate images instead of a JSON file:

```
var imgs = ["image01.png","image02.png","image03.png","image04.png"];
var textures = [];

for (var i=0; i < 4; i++)
{
     textures.push(PIXI.Texture.fromImage(imgs[i]));
};

var mc = new PIXI.MovieClip(textures);
```